# $\frac{1}{x}$ not integrable on interval $[a,b]$ where $a<0$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I know that $\frac{1}{x}$ is not riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ since if we try to find the integral we get that $ln x|^{x=1}_{x=0}=ln1-ln0=-ln 0$, which is undefined.

I was wondering if this is true for $\frac{1}{x}$ for any interval where after taking the antiderivative we get some negative number  $t$ and so we can't calculate $ln t$. That is, for an interval $[a,b]$ where $a\leq 0$.

Or would it always be zero, since $\int_{-5}^5\frac{1} {x}=ln|x||^5_{-5}=ln5-ln5=0$? (since $|5|=|-5|$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. The function $f(x)=\frac1x$ is not integrable on an interval $[a,b]$ if and only if $0\in[a,b]$. To see that $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ where $a<b<0$, note that
$$\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=-\int_{-b}^{-a}f(x)\ dx.$$
This is why we usually write the antiderivative of $\frac1x$ as $\ln|x|$ rather that $\ln x$.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance